# The Error: "A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]" should not apply

Tags: java, arrays, rest, jaxb

I have a class ShipmentRequest which was initialized through JAXB.

In my main class to send a REST-API POST-Request I am filling an object of this class with the needed input and put it in a JSONArray

```
public JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(shipmentRequest);
```

And finally I am starting the POST:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://someURL/services/rest/url")
.queryString("access_token","someTokenCode")
.body(array.get(0)).asJson();
```

I do not understand the error, because when I use myJSONArray.toJSONString() I get following output:

```
[{"Id":"123456","Reference":"Send","transport":{"transporterCode":"Deliverer","trackAndTrace":"someCode123456"}}]
```

What am I missing? My first character is a '[' ?

EDIT 1, Code of ShipmentRequest

```
//
// Diese Datei wurde mit der JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.8-b130911.1802 generiert 
// Siehe <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Änderungen an dieser Datei gehen bei einer Neukompilierung des Quellschemas verloren. 
// Generiert: 2017.10.18 um 11:02:47 AM CEST 
//


package bol.shipment;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java-Klasse für anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="OrderItemId" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long"/>
 *         &lt;element name="ShipmentReference" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Transport" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="TransporterCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                   &lt;element name="TrackAndTrace" type="{https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd}TrackAndTrace" minOccurs="0"/>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *         &lt;element name="ShippingLabelCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "orderItemId",
    "shipmentReference",
    "transport",
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ShipmentRequest")
public class ShipmentRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "OrderItemId")
    protected String orderItemId;
    @XmlElement(name = "ShipmentReference", required = true)
    protected String shipmentReference;
    @XmlElement(name = "Transport")
    protected ShipmentRequest.Transport transport;

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der orderItemId-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     */
    public String getOrderItemId() {
        return orderItemId;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der orderItemId-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     */
    public void setOrderItemId(String value) {
        this.orderItemId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der shipmentReference-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getShipmentReference() {
        return shipmentReference;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der shipmentReference-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setShipmentReference(String value) {
        this.shipmentReference = value;
    }

    /**
     * Ruft den Wert der transport-Eigenschaft ab.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ShipmentRequest.Transport }
     *     
     */
    public ShipmentRequest.Transport getTransport() {
        return transport;
    }

    /**
     * Legt den Wert der transport-Eigenschaft fest.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ShipmentRequest.Transport }
     *     
     */
    public void setTransport(ShipmentRequest.Transport value) {
        this.transport = value;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Java-Klasse für anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>Das folgende Schemafragment gibt den erwarteten Content an, der in dieser Klasse enthalten ist.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="TransporterCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
     *         &lt;element name="TrackAndTrace" type="{https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd}TrackAndTrace" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "transporterCode",
        "trackAndTrace"
    })
    public static class Transport {

        @XmlElement(name = "TransporterCode")
        protected String transporterCode;
        @XmlElement(name = "TrackAndTrace")
        protected String trackAndTrace;

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der transporterCode-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getTransporterCode() {
            return transporterCode;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der transporterCode-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setTransporterCode(String value) {
            this.transporterCode = value;
        }

        /**
         * Ruft den Wert der trackAndTrace-Eigenschaft ab.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public String getTrackAndTrace() {
            return trackAndTrace;
        }

        /**
         * Legt den Wert der trackAndTrace-Eigenschaft fest.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link String }
         *     
         */
        public void setTrackAndTrace(String value) {
            this.trackAndTrace = value;
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT 2:
My Request should look like this!

```
<ShipmentRequest xmlns="https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2.1/plazaapi.xsd">
 <OrderItemId>1234567890</OrderItemId>
 <ShipmentReference>A321SR</ShipmentReference>
 <Transport>
   <TransporterCode>TNT</TransporterCode>
   <TrackAndTrace>3SBOL0987654321</TrackAndTrace>
 </Transport>
</ShipmentRequest>
```

EDIT 3:
I tried filling a JSONObject with these:

```
private JSONArray shipmentRequestArray = new JSONArray();
private JSONArray transportArray = new JSONArray();
private JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();

transportArray.add(new JSONObject().append("TransporterCode", transporter_Code));
transportArray.add(new JSONObject().append("TrackAndTrace", track_And_Trace));
shipmentRequestArray.add(new JSONObject().append("OrderItemId", orderItemIdTEST));
shipmentRequestArray.add(new JSONObject().append("ShipmentReference", shipment_Reference));
shipmentRequestArray.add(transportArray);

requestObject.put("ShipmentRequest", shipmentRequestArray);
```

And when I tried this with:

```
.body(requestObject).asJson();
```

I get the new error:
No serializer found for class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

EDIT 4:
My example response should look like this:

```
Status: 201 created

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:ProcessStatus xmlns:ns1="https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/xsd/v2/plazaapi.xsd">
 <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
 <ns1:sellerId>1084486</ns1:sellerId>
 <ns1:entityId>1234567890</ns1:entityId>
 <ns1:eventType>CONFIRM_SHIPMENT</ns1:eventType>
 <ns1:description>Confirm shipment for order item 1234567890.</ns1:description>
 <ns1:status>PENDING</ns1:status>
 <ns1:createTimestamp>2016-02-17T17:30:00.142+01:00</ns1:createTimestamp>
 <ns1:Links>
   <ns1:link ns1:method="GET" ns1:href="https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/rest/process-status/v2/1234567" ns1:rel="self"/>
 </ns1:Links>
</ns1:ProcessStatus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is about wrong type of object. First character should be '[', but it's not - I guess its '{'.

It is because you are executing `array.get(0)`, which returns you an JSONObject, where JSONArray is required.

UPD:

I did some debugging with additional info you provided.
Problem was that `Unirest.post` returns an object of RequestBodyEntity class. To convert it to json you need to get body of answer first via `getBody()`.

Thats what worked for me:

```
ShipmentRequest shipmentRequest = new ShipmentRequest();
shipmentRequest.setOrderItemId("1234567890");
shipmentRequest.setShipmentReference("A321SR");
ShipmentRequest.Transport transport = new ShipmentRequest.Transport();
transport.setTrackAndTrace("3SBOL0987654321");
transport.setTransporterCode("TNT");
shipmentRequest.setTransport(transport);

String jsonRequest = new Gson().toJson(shipmentRequest);
RequestBodyEntity result = Unirest.post("https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/rest/shipments/v2")
    .queryString(
       "access_token",
       "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaWQiOjMzMTgsInNlcSI6MSwidHlwIjoiYXBpIiwidnNuIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTc2NjF9.hVdtwBfJAVfRVeBdf1XDAxe7Qpigwa0wmCvnF_Bicc8")
    .body(jsonRequest);
System.out.println(new Gson().fromJson(result.getBody().toString(), ShipmentRequest.class));
```

You need to use `result.getBody()` to return object that you want.
After this you can do

```
System.out.println(result.getBody().toString())
```

to print it or

```
new Gson().fromJson(result.getBody().toString(), ShipmentRequest.class)
```

to save it into object of ShipmentRequest type.

Comment: I already tried executing with just array, but this results in the same exception

Comment: Can you post the code of ShipmentRequest?
And which version of JSON library are you using?

Comment: I edited my code with ShipmentRequest, where do I see the version? In my maven dependencies I have unirest-java version 1.4.9 and jackson version 2.9.4

Comment: You can see library version in maven dependencies. But I think you use json-simple for serialization, because of calls to `toJSONString` method.

Then my idea is that you need to wrap you JSONArray into JSONObject, so resulting json would be like {"myarray": ["name1":"value1"]}, and not like ["name1":"value1"].

And take a look at https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: The problem I am having, if my object I give is a JSONObject i get following error: No serializer found for class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) I tried all kinds of things to end that problem, but nothing worked

Comment: Basically all you need to to is to serialize/deserialize object as JSON.

I would suggest to use GSON library as it is very popular and easy solution for such problem.
https://github.com/google/gson
All you need to do is to add it as maven dependency and then call `new Gson().toJson(yourObject)` or `new Gson().fromJson(object, yourClass.class)`

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/

Comment: my request looks like this: .body(new Gson().toJson(object)).asJson(); But I still get the "JSON Array must start with...." exception. Am I assuming right that, the API WANTS a JSON Array and not JSON Object?

Comment: But the thing is that I can not use a JSON Object to wrap my JSONArray in it, because I need a JSONArray. See my edit

Comment: The request you attached is XML, not JSON. But for it's structure it is definitely an object, not array. So from information I have for now -  you should use JSON Object

Comment: `HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/rest/shipments/v2")
     .queryString("access_token",
       "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaWQiOjMzMTgsInNlcSI6MSwidHlwIjoiYXBpIiwidnNuIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTc2NjF9.hVdtwBfJAVfRVeBdf1XDAxe7Qpigwa0wmCvnF_Bicc8")
     .body(new Gson().toJson(object)).asJson();` Here I give my JSONObject object as a POST request. But I still get the error: "A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

Comment: Thank you for additional information.
I updated answer with working example, please take a look @akBen

Comment: I tried your example. It works so far that I do not get an error message! Thank you very much. BUT ;-): When I POST my request to the url I should get another Response then ShipmentRequest (See Edit4), But I only the the ShipmentRequest back and not the ProcessStatus?

Comment: I don't have access to this API (access token "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaWQiOjMzMTgsInNlcSI6MSwidHlwIjoiYXBpIiwidnNuIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTc2NjF9.hVdtwBfJAVfRVeBdf1XDAxe7Qpigwa0wmCvnF_Bicc8"  - you posted it yesterday - has expired today).

From what can I say, you are making an API call to `https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/rest/shipments/v2`. I don't know the description of this endpoint, what it expects as input, what it provides as output. Can you provide a documentation/source code for this? Maybe you need to send an xml and not json

Comment: I saw it. I dont have api keys to generate an authorization header to execute POST query, and iI wont create a seller account for this.

Comment: And I do not want/force/need you to make one.^^ But I thought Unirest ist together with jackson and/or json converting my ShipmentRequest to an xml file which this API wants?

Comment: Can you try follow code?
`HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://plazaapi.bol.com/services/rest/shipments/v2")
            .queryString(
                "access_token",
                "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjaWQiOjMzMTgsInNlcSI6MSwidHlwIjoiYXBpIiwidnNuIjoxLCJuYmYiOjE1MTcyOTc2NjF9.hVdtwBfJAVfRVeBdf1XDAxe7Qpigwa0wmCvnF_Bicc8")
            .body(jsonRequest).asString();
        System.out.println(response);`
replace `access_token` with actual one

Comment: Already tried:
sysout: com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse@1a5a4e19

Error:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Please take a look at this code snippet:
https://pastebin.com/rT4yttML
When you run it, you will see in terminal an error which says that actually the answer is in xml. You need to get a string representation of it and then transform it to java object.

Can you provide me an valid access_token for today?

Comment: When I run this snippet, I only get the same error message as my message one above. I can not provide you with a newer token, because this is the token I use. It becomes valid for 15 minutes, when I try my request.